# similarity between non-colored images

Tags: image, image-processing, similarity

I want to find percentage similarity between uncolored images. Specifically, I want to compare my own drawing with an image. Here's an example image:

[image: Example image]

I don't have any knowledge about image-processing. What algorithms can be used to achieve my goal? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: this is absolutely what I wonder!

Comment: Can you include some drawing you pretend to compare against the image ? Currently, your problem is unsolvable because there are no restrictions on it.

Comment: I couldn't draw it but I found something on internet. Imagine something like this: http://cf.sketchfu.com/i/4081460.png :P

Comment: That looks a cat to me, not a lion. You are now in the realm of heuristics + machine learning, you can't "solve" it otherwise (you won't solve it either with these tools, but you can get something that might be good enough). Google for CBIR (Content Based Image Retrieval) for a general view into what you are after.

Comment: If you are planning to copy the image by hand as closely as you can and then computing a comparison metric to see how well you did, that is probably quite doable. If you want to compare unguided drawings of the same object (e.g. a lion) by different people, that is nigh on impossible. Please clarify.

Comment: first one. I am planning to draw it similarly as close as I can looking at the image.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are both black and white, you could compute the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).  In simple words, each black pixel is a point. For each point of image A, you compute the closest point of image B. You get a list of distances. The Hausdorff distance, is the greatest value of this list. The smaller it is, the more similar your images are.
You will have to compute this for several relative position/angle/aspect ratio between your two images, in order to find the position that matches the best.

You can extend this method to any non B&W image by computing the edges.